# How to tell if SQL Query Store is forcing the plan when executing a query in SSMS

Tags: sql-server, execution-plan, query-store

Just wondering if there's an easy way to tell if the execution plan is being forced by query store when running a query in SSMS.

Comment: Query store is a Async action for save plans, this plan save after running plan to query store. we can't see forced plan, when query is running, and we don't need this... at least you can decrease time of save and analysis query plans set auto refresh 1 second for view result.